# R - Loop lm() columnwise through Dataframe with missing Values

Tags: r, loops, apply, lm

I'm working with a data frame comprised of at least three variables (wavelength, irradiance, x), which I have pivoted so that each wavelength is a new row thus allowing me to run lm() on each wavelength and extract the coefficient so I can see how x changes with wavelength and irradiance.

However, the only way I've been able to get it to work is by explicitly running lm() on each wavelength. This won't be feasible with larger data frames which will have hundreds of parameters which change as a function of wavelength and irradiance.

I have a feeling this can be addressed using 'apply' or writing a loop but I haven't had any luck making them work.

See below for an example of the issue.

I'm still pretty new so any pointers are appreciated

```
irr = rnorm(33, 10, 3)
wave = c(290, 290, 290, 300, 300, 300, 310, 310, 310, 320, 320, 320, 330, 330, 330, 340, 340, 340, 350, 350, 350, 360, 360, 360, 370, 370, 370, 380, 380, 380, 400, 400, 400)
x = rnorm(33, 50, 2)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(wave, irr, x))
df_wide <- df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "wave",
              values_from = "x")
"290_lm" <- lm(df_wide$`290` ~ df_wide$irr) 
"300_lm" <- lm(df_wide$`300` ~ df_wide$irr) #etc through each wavelength

## Attempt at loop

for (i in 2:(ncol(df_wide))){
  irr <- df_wide[2][i]
  lm_function <- paste(irr,
                       sep = "~")
  df_lm = lm(lm_function, 
             data = df_wide[2:12])
}
```

Comment: I would recommend not to pivot,and instead use the `subset` option of `lm`. I also wonder what is the dependent and the independent variable in your linear model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from your description your problem is identical to the example for `purrr::map`, which avoids the need to go wide.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

results_list <- 
  df %>% 
  split(.$wave) %>% 
  map(~ lm(x ~ irr, data = .x)) %>% 
  map(summary)

results_list$`350`
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = x ~ irr, data = .x)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>      19      20      21 
#>  0.2924 -2.2947  2.0023 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
#> (Intercept)  52.7276     6.2200   8.477   0.0748 .
#> irr          -0.4977     0.6229  -0.799   0.5708  
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 3.059 on 1 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.3897, Adjusted R-squared:  -0.2206 
#> F-statistic: 0.6385 on 1 and 1 DF,  p-value: 0.5708
```

Based on your data

```r
irr = rnorm(33, 10, 3)
wave = c(290, 290, 290, 300, 300, 300, 310, 310, 310, 320, 320, 320, 330, 330, 330, 340, 340, 340, 350, 350, 350, 360, 360, 360, 370, 370, 370, 380, 380, 380, 400, 400, 400)
x = rnorm(33, 50, 2)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(wave, irr, x))
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

additional solution

```
library(tidyverse)
library(generics)
df %>% 
  group_by(wave) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data, ~ lm(x ~ irr, data = .x) %>% tidy)) %>% 
  select(-data) %>% 
  unnest(model)
```

Comment: Nice approach, but I had to load package **generics** in addition. (Tested with R 4.0.0, packages from last week).

Comment: Function `tidy` or more precisely `tidy.lm` is found in package **broom**: Package **generics** is just another wrapper. So instead of `library(generics)` one may also use `library(broom)`

Answer (score 1):

Or like follows:

```
df <- data.frame(
  irr = rnorm(33, 10, 3),
  wave = c(290, 290, 290, 300, 300, 300, 310, 310, 310, 
           320, 320, 320, 330, 330, 330, 340, 340, 340, 350, 350, 350, 
           360, 360, 360, 370, 370, 370, 380, 380, 380, 400, 400, 400),
  x = rnorm(33, 50, 2)

)

mylm <- function(w) {
  m <- lm(x ~ irr, data = df, subset = (wave == w))
  ## outcomment the following if you just need the parameters
  # coef(m)
}

lapply(df$wave, mylm)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a ton easier when you stay in long format. Just subset your data using `lapply`. With `setNames` the resulting list gets nice names.

```
res <- setNames(lapply(unique(df$wave), function(w) 
  lm(x ~ irr, data=df[df$wave %in% w, ])),
  paste0("wave.", unique(df$wave)))
res
# $wave.290
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = x ~ irr, data = df[df$wave %in% w, ])
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)          irr  
# 36.837        1.503  
# 
# 
# $wave.300
# 
# Call:
#   lm(formula = x ~ irr, data = df[df$wave %in% w, ])
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)          irr  
# 54.3785      -0.5586 
# [...]
```